# How to make spawn process inherit stdio only or error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In general i'm making builds and i want to get output only when an error occurs.

Right now im inheriting stdio as you can see in my code but it outputs alot of unnecessary noise.

Is there a way to only output errors ?

```
getDirectories(__dirname).map(dirName => {
  try {
    process.chdir(dirName);
    spawn('npm run build', { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });
    process.chdir('../');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`chdir: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of child process documentation, you may filter only the stderr using following options,

```
// Spawn child sharing only stderr
spawn('npm run build', [], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'inherit']});
```

or

```
// Spawn child sharing only stderr
spawn('npm run build', [], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stderr] });
```

For further information please follow the [stdio.options documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio).